# Change the target framework for project in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-4.8, .net-8.0

I am currently using .NET 8.0 Target Framework for my Visual Studio project.

I have downloaded .NET FRAMEWORK 4.8.1, but I don't see it in the drop down to change it on the application screen.

Is there another way I can convert this project to a .NET FRAMEWORK 4.8 project?

[Project Properties Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/You8J.png)

Edit: I have decided to not try and go back in time to make this change and want to add ReportViewer to .net-8.0

I have followed this github to do this https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore/.

But after installed the NuGet packages and I am now getting this error when I try to add it to the toolbox.

[image: Choose Toolbox Items]

I have found this information that is similar to this but is referencing a UserForm.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/still-cannot-add-a-winforms-control-to-the-vs-tool/1626082

Comment: .NET 8.0 is part of the **.NET Core** family of environments, while .NET 4.8.1 is from the legacy/Windows-only classic **.NET** framework - those are not directly compatible (different base class libraries, different runtimes), and you cannot directly switch from one to the other

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, essentially I can't convert this?

Comment: Create a new .NET 4.8.1 project and copy over the C# source files, so that you have all the correct references and base class libraries and all. Going from classic .NET to .NET Core is already a **migration** - going back is even a bit more tedious, sorry

Comment: I have already started that process, but I am struggling to copy over a Form[design]. I don't know how to copy a design and keep all of the fields and components.

Comment: Sorry, can't help there - never felt the urge to "go back in time" to an old, unsupported framework with no more innovation and development. All my migrations have been from .NET away towards .NET Core ....

Comment: The urge to go back in time is .NET 8.0 does not support ReportViewer and I need that for this project. I have it in the toolbox but it is greyed out, not accessible.

Comment: There should be a way to create these separately and then use them together. I don't know anything about your business needs or what you're building, but you could build a ReportViewer .NET 4.81. website, for example, and access that via some methodology from your .NET Core app.  You don't necessarily need to combine two apps or websties to use them in concert. Also, it looks like you're not the [first to try this](https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore/).

Comment: @marc_s Framework is far from being 'unsupported'. Even 4.6.2 is still [supported until 2027](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework). They can't drop support when so many of their own products are still built on it (including Visual Studio itself!)

Comment: Try creating new .NET 4.8 Framework app (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/74849791/2501279, be sure to select required app type) and move files to it.

Answer (score 0):

> I have downloaded .NET FRAMEWORK 4.8.1, but I don't see it in the drop
> down to change it on the application screen.
>
> here another way I can convert this project to a .NET FRAMEWORK 4.8
> project?

First of all, Visual Studio 2022 is [intended for .NET 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) and later version. You might seen 3.1 which should be showing out of support. So  as  `.NET Framework 4.8` is a legacy framework, and Microsoft recommends using newer .NET versions (.NET Core, .NET 5, or later) thus, it hasn't been integrated along with visual studio 2022 by default. Not even the runtime attached as well.

However, In order to include your expected legacy framework, within your visual studio installer, you could click on `Modify`

[image]

Then go to `Individial Component` select your framework as following:

[image]

Once you install the above updated, now you should be seen your selected framework in dropdown list thus the project type. If you still doesn't seen the expected version in dropdown,  make sure that you have the .NET Framework 4.8 SDK installed on your machine manually as well.

Furthermore, you can also [check for another work around](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-a-target-framework) here in this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-a-target-framework) here.

**Note:** After changing the target framework, rebuild the project to ensure everything works as expected. This will update references and configurations for the new target framework. In addition, If you don't have any specific requirement to the legacy runtime, its recommended to use updated version as there are huge performence and feature improvement in latest version. Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) for additional information.

Comment: _"visual studio 2022 is intended for .NET 6 and later version."_ - This and the following is a very bold statement =)

Comment: Yeah indeed, finding legacy version within it is kind of unexpected because lagacy app should open with it but intended version shouldn't be in dropdown. However, I tried to exaplain, sir, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 works perfectly well for developing applications using .NET Framework.

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: What exactly you are getting any error or target framework doesn't displaying?

Comment: Have you installed SDK for .NET 4.8 on your machine?